# 13.10 Drag and Drop not working

Tags: 13.10

I am unable to drag and drop items to my Ubuntu 13.10 destop. It keeps giving me this error.

```
Erro ao Copiar.
erro ao copiar. houve um erro ao obter informação sobre "/".
```

English:

```
Error in Copying
There was an error getting information about "/".
```

[image]

Comment: If you don't own the file you're trying to DnD then use copy & paste instead

Comment: Ok, but why appear There was an error getting information about "/". And in my 12.04 not appeared?

Comment: This is a change from previous, you can't DnD files you don't own including those in /usr/share/applications (most common occurrence of what you're seeing.) There is likely a bug report on DnD from /usr/share/applications but don't expect this will be changed..

Comment: You can include DnD from the Dash in above, not allowed if you don't own

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1241972) with Unity 7.1. It occurs when you drag an app from Dash and try to drop on Desktop.

You can use alternate method(s) to create a desktop shortcut. You can try this,

- Go to the folder /usr/share/applications.
- Find the program you want.
- Then right click on it and copy.
- Now go to your home folder and open up the Desktop folder.
- Right click and then select paste.

Comment: I hope they will fix it soon.

Comment: And when this bug will be fix?

Comment: Appeared again in 14.04 also. Hell, no fix even for LTS, what Ubuntu Developers are doing, messing and corrupting code, nothing else